# .startswith not working

Tags: python, file-io, for-loop, if-statement

In My program I have a file and then I read through all the lines in a for loop checking each line for what it begins with. Then adding each line as a variable. There are a little over 40 lines in this and they are all pretty much the same but one of the elif statements doesnt return true the .startswith isnt working. anyways here is the file contents basically a bunch of saved information fN would be the variable I saved and john would be what I want it to be. So this method does just that or it is suppose to

```
fN:john
fP:1
fE:father email
mN:mother name
mP:1
mE:mother email @ bomg.com
a:1233 adress lane
c:city
s:state
zC:1234534
hP:(1928)phone-1123
cP:1113333
eN:emergancy
eNu:number
c1N:cluubiie 1
c1G:1st
c1B:1-23-34
c2N:clubbie 2
c2G:grade 2
c2B:birth 2
c3N:clubb 3 
c3G:grade 3
c3B:birth 3
```

Method

```
def fillWindow(self,student):
    global fileDirectory
    location = os.path.join(fileDirectory, student + '.txt')
    file = open(location, 'r')

    for line in file.xreadlines():
        if line.startswith('fN'):
            fN = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('fP'):
            fP = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('fE'):
            fE = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('mN'):
            mN = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('mP'):
            mP = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('mE'):
            mE = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('a'):
            a = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c'):
            c = line.split(':')[1] 
        elif line.startswith('s'):
            s = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('zC'):
            zC = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('hP'):
            hP = line.split(':')[1]
```

> right here True is never returned even though in the file there is a line that starts with cP

```
        elif line.startswith('cP'):
            cP = line.split(':')[1]
            print('True') 
        elif line.startswith('eN'):
            eN = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('eNu'):
            eNu = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c1N'):
            c1N = line.split(':')[1] 
        elif line.startswith('c1G'):
            c1G = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c1B'):
            c1B = line.split(':')[1] 
        elif line.startswith('c2N'):
            c2N = line.split(':')[1] 
        elif line.startswith('c2G'):
            c2G = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c2B'):
            c2B = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c3N'):
            c3N = line.split(':')[1] 
        elif line.startswith('c3G'):
            c3G = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c3B'):
            c3B = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c4N'):
            c4N = line.split(':')[1] 
        elif line.startswith('c4G'):
            c4G = line.split(':')[1]
        elif line.startswith('c4B'):
            c4B = line.split(':')[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work because a line starts with `cP` also starts with `c`, and you placed the `c` condition before `cP`.

---

You should better refactor your code to avoid the long if/elif chain. It is very unmaintainable. I would use a dictionary and

```
 results = {}
 for line in file:
    (key, value) = line.split(':', 1)
    results[key] = value

 # use results['fN'] for your fN variable
```

or even shorter:

```
 results = dict(line.split(':', 1) for line in file)
```

(If you must use fN as an independent local variable, you could use

```
 locals().update(line.split(':', 1) for line in file)
```

but I don't recommend it.)

Comment: Idk if you have used Tkinter but I'm trying to put all these variables into different entry boxes and I don't think I can do that with a dictionary. or more likely I don't know how

Comment: @Brandon: Why you can't use a dictionary with Tkinter?

Comment: well to add a string to a entry box you have to have string.insert() and I don't know how I would do that if all the strings I needed were in a dictionary

Comment: dumb question dict[key] returns a string

Answer (score 8):

You should think about how these two lines interact:

```
elif line.startswith('c'):
...
elif line.startswith('cP'):
```

Also, you should look into using a dictionary to hold all your values, you could drastically shorten your program.

Answer (score 6):

That's a pretty horrible chunk of code. Do you really need all those elements to be individual variables? Why not a dictionary along these lines:

```
{'fN':'john',
 'fP':'1',
   ...
}
```

which you could generate in a couple of lines only:

```
dct = {}
f = file(location, 'r')
for line in f:
    k, v = line.split(':')
    dct[k] = v
```

Comment: `line.split(":", 1)` might be preferable in case the value contains another colon.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `elif` for all alternatives but the first one, at most one of the alternatives ever gets evaluated.  For a line starting with `cP`, the condition

```
elif line.startswith('c'):
```

will also hold, so none of the further alternatives will be considered.

That said, you might be better off storing your result in a dictionary, maybe like this:

```
d = dict(line.split(":", 1) for line in open(location))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the names fN , fP , fE , mN, mP, .... are manifestly known and steady, and since the **self** in your definition of the function betrays you want to create attributes of an instance with values read in the file, and since the file has a CSV format, my proposition is to do:

```
import csv

class A:
def __init__(self):
    self.fN  = self.fP  = self.fE  = None 
    self.mN  = self.mP  = self.mE  = None
    self.a   = self.c   = self.s   = None
    self.zC  = self.hP  = self.cP  = None
    self.eN  = self.c1N = self.c1G = None
    self.c1B = self.c2N = self.c2G = None
    self.c2B = self.c3N = self.c3G = None
    self.c3B = None

inst1 = A()

with open('roro.txt','rb') as f:
    rid = csv.reader(f,delimiter=':')
    for row in rid:
        inst1.__dict__[row[0]] = row[1]


print inst1.fP
print inst1.s
print inst1.c3B
```

Note that naming an object with the name of a built-in function ( that is to say **file**) is a bad practice, and that **xreadlines()** is deprecated.

.

Moreover, what is your intention by defining `global fileDirectory` ?

The statement `global x` specifies that if the creation of an object is done thanks to an assignement done to name **x** in the next lines, the object of name **x** must be considered as being in the module of global level. In your code there is no assignement to **fileDirectory** and it's better because declaring **fileDirectory** as global could provoke unsuspected errors.

Note that the global level is the higher level , not the outside level of a function. Examine the following code:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.m = 0.00315879

    N = 101

    def f(self,x,y):
        print 'in f : x==',x,"  y+10==",y
        def g(a,b):
            print 'in g : a==',a,'  b==',b
            global m
            global N
            m = a*b
            N = 5000010000
            print 'in g : m = a*b ==',m
            print 'in g : N==',N


        g(x+300,y+700)
        print 'in f, outside g: m==',m
        print 'in f, outside g: N==',N



u = A()


u.f(0,40)
print
print 'm at the global level==',m
print 'N at the global level==',N
print 'the instance attribute u.m==',u.m
print 'the class attribute u.N==',u.N
```

result

```
in f : x== 0   y+10== 40
in g : a== 300   b== 740
in g : m = a*b == 222000
in g : N== 5000010000
in f, outside g: m== 222000
in f, outside g: N== 5000010000

m at the global level== 222000
N at the global level== 5000010000
the instance attribute u.m== 0.00315879
the class attribute u.N== 101
```

Comment: responding only to the global variable question. It is because the file directory is needed in many different parts of the program so I made it a global variable

Comment: @Brandon OK, but at what level is the object of name **fileDirectory** created ? We don't see this creation in your function **fillWindow()** as it is written. The statement **global** is useless if there is no creation-assignement in the next lines, as far as I understand the **global** statement

Comment: idk what the name of the level is but it is the highest, right next to the imports

Comment: @Brandon If the object of name **fileDirectory** is created at the highest level (you mean the module of name **__main__** , doesn't it ?), then the statement ``global fileDirectory`` in a lower level is absolutely useless. You should study the manner Python manages the variables (in the docs 'variable' means 'name'), in (http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) : _"When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is called the block’s environment."_

Comment: @Brandon That means that if a function **h()** is defined in a function **g()** that is defined in a function **f()** that is defined in a module **M** , the involvment of a name (aka "variable") X in a statement in the body of **h()** triggers the interpreter to search the binding between X and the object pointed by X in the namespace of the function **h()** , and if X isn't found in this namespace then Python searches in the enclosing scope that is to say in the namespace of function **g()**;

Comment: @Brandon if it doesn't find X again there, it will search in the namespace of function **f**, and after that in the namespace of module **M** if necessary again.

Comment: @Brandon So if **fileDirectory** is defined at the module level, statement **global** is useless: the interpreter will go to the module level to find it: _"If a variable is used in a code block but not defined there, it is a free variable."_ But evidently, these explorations of successive namespaces are a lot of work for the interpreter; that's why it is preferable to pass names of objects that will be used in a function as an argument of this function when this one is called.